# Catchable fatal error: Object of class PDOStatement could not be converted to string in

Tags: php, pdo

My query is as simple as blow: But I don't understand why I'm getting this **error=>  Catchable fatal error: Object of class PDOStatement could not be converted to string in**

```
$sub_id=4;
include('inc/config.php');
 echo $statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE subid=:q");
$statement->execute(array(':q' => $sub_id));
while($row = $statement->fetch())
{
     $tutor=$row['Name'];

}
```

Comment: Why do you have to echo it? It's not a valid value for echo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't `echo` the `$statement` variable as it is a `PDOStatement Object` so you need to read up on how to use PDO : )